# Changing axes in tikz-3dplot picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

As is, the axes in the following picture

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=east]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

are as follows:

- x-axis: to the right
- y-axis: up
- z-axis: towards you

What do I need to do to achieve the following:

- x-axis: towards you
- y-axis: to the right
- z-axis: up

It goes without saying that any coordinates entered must observe the changed axes.

Comment: Can you express this axis change as a rotation somehow? If you can figure out the Euler rotation angles for the transformation, it's easy to add that in `tikz-3dplot`.

Comment: I think it's a 90-degree rotation about the x-axis, followed by one about the z-axis, or about the z-axis followed by the y-axis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the coordinate matrix transformation option `cm=...`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=east]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm]
    \draw[thick,->,black] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=east]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** TikZ provides a coordinate transformation matrix cm = (a,b;c,d) that can be used to transform the coordinates (x,y) into a new set of coordinates (X,Y) = (a,b;c,d)*(x,y) = (ax+by;cx+dy). In the OP's case we want the direction of X to be 'towards you', i.e. X = -x - y. The Y coordinate must be 'to the right', i.e. Y = x. Solving for a, b, c and d we find
a = -1, 
b = -1, 
c = 1
d = 0
This is what is given in the option cm={a,b,c,d,(0,0)} where (0,0) is the x- and y-shift of the origo. 
The new Z coordinate is Z = X + Y = -y.

Before being plotted, the coordinates are multiplied with the TikZ unit vectors. Default is x=1cm, y=1cm and z=-3.85mm. Thus to get the same length and direction  of the axis in the new orientation we need to change this to x=3.85mm, y=1cm and z=-1cm. As y=1cm is the default this is left out.

I am not sure the above is clear... Feel free to improve the explanation.

Comment: I took a look at the manual on cm=, and my brain now hurts. Would you care to add some comments on your use of cm= in this instance, plus an explanation of x= and z=? That would transform your answer from an example into a learning opportunity! Thanks in advance (+1)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I have tried to explain the transformation. There are two steps: rotate the (x,y) plane using the `cm` matrix and then change the TikZ unit vectors using `x=` and `z=` options.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! (I love this website: you ask your question, you go to bed, when you wake up in the morning your problem has been solved by the (TeX)powers that be :-) I wish the rest of the world worked this way too ...

Answer (score 8):

In fact all you have to do is change the first 2 lines:

Default axis orientation is as you have stated.

[image]

So:

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{105} % rotate 60 degrees around x axis, then 105 degrees about z
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
```

The command from the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/) is as follows [(see also this example)](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/440-tikz-3dplot)

Syntax: `\tdplotsetmaincoords{ theta }{ phi }`

Parameters:

- theta: The angle (in degrees) through which the coordinate frame is rotated
  about the x axis.
- phi: The angle (in degrees) through which the coordinate frame is rotated
  about the z axis.

[image]