# Can I set z-axis to point to the right with tikz-3dplot?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

All I want to do is to rotate the axes of the accepted answer of the question in

[How to draw and annotate a spherical coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116206/how-to-draw-and-annotate-a-spherical-coordinate-system)

such that the new z-axis stays where the current y-axis is.

My new axes (say, x', y' and z') should seem to be exactly where those xyz-axes are but with the following correspondences:

- z' <-- y
- y' <-- x
- x' <-- z

**I don't want simply to change the axes' labels**, because I want to work with the axis z' still being along the direction (0,0,1) and the angle theta must still come from it.

Stuff from [How to draw and annotate a spherical coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116206/how-to-draw-and-annotate-a-spherical-coordinate-system) below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
\draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
\draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
    {\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't to that with `\tdplotsetmaincoords{}{}` because that command only rotates around x-axis and then around the new z-axis (from the configuration showed below), and reaching my configuration requires a third rotation (like Euler angles) or rotation around y-axis.

This is a picture from [Changing axes in tikz-3dplot picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/changing-axes-in-tikz-3dplot-picture) (bobobobo's answer) showing the start configuration for rotations with tdplotsetmaincoords

[image: Start configuration for rotations with command tdplotsetmaincoords{}{}.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to do that with `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}`. I also had to put `\tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}` instead of `\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}`.

[image: Rotated spherical coordinate angles.]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{-90}{0}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
  \def\rvec{1}
  \def\thetavec{45}
  \def\phivec{30}
  \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
  \draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
  \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
  \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
%  \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pyz);
%  \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxz);
%  \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxz);
  \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north east}{$\phi$}
  \tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
  \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```